# What are the different game modes?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Upon attempting to create a new world in Don't Starve Together I am presented with the opportunity to select a Game Mode.

The options include: **Survival**, **Wilderness** and **Endless**

What are the differences between these 3 modes?

Which is the best for casual gameplay? IE. has least death penalties, I do not wish to continue playing once my co-op player or I die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this wiki page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Don't_Starve_Together):

**Survival**

- Intended to encourage cooperative play.
- When players die, they become [ghosts](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_Players).
- Ghosts cause the sanity of living players to drop if they are nearby.
- Ghosts can be revived by certain items.
- When all players die a timer starts. If nobody revives themselves before the timer is up, the world resets and all players start anew.

**Endless**

- Intended to be more relaxed and casual.
- When players die, they become ghosts.
- Ghosts have no effect on the sanity of living players.
- Ghosts can be revived by the same items as Survival, but also at the [spawn portal](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Jury-Rigged_Portal).
- Even if everyone becomes ghosts, the world never resets.

**Wilderness**

- Intended to be more like other survival games.
- Players spawn in random locations.
- When players die they do not become ghosts.
- Dead players lose all their items and map information, and respawn at a new
  random location.

Comment: To complete the answer I must suggest that the most casual of these is *Endless* where if you die you just go back to the portal and rez. This is the one we find the most enjoyable with friends and its the most hardcore-_less_

Comment: For Wilderness, what does "lose all their items" mean?  Does it just refer to inventory, or to other items such as items in a chest, an ice box, or Chester?  Does it mean those items are dropped on the ground, or that they vanish from existence?